# Magento 2 How to get collection in SOAP UI?

Tags: magento2, collection, soap-api

I am trying to get all SOAP api collection in SOAP UI, The initial step is wrong, Everytime it fails when I write Initial WSDL.

> Initial WSDL:

```
https://127.0.0.1/magento/soap/all/?wsdl&services=catalogCategoryRepositoryV1
```

I tried by follwing url aswell, but no luck:

```
http://127.0.0.1/magento/soap/all?wsdl_list=1
http://127.0.0.1/magento/soap/all?wsdl&services=integrationAdminTokenServiceV1
```

Initially my requirement is, I wanted category collection and then all products of any particular category.

> Please provide some solution on this,

I have Authentication key, and Content-type which we used to get collection in REST API via POSTMAN, but this time I am using SOAPUI for running SOAP API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read this tutorial from starting and follow it, then you will get your answer without any issue:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/soap/bk-soap.html[enter link description here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/soap/bk-soap.html)

This tutorial is providing by **DevDocs**, it will help you alot.

Comment: ok I am checking it now.